# Como mantener centrado un formulario

Tags: c#

tengo un formulario el cual inicia en un tamaño especifico y mediante un timer, va haciendo mal alto y ancho, pero tengo un problema, al utilizar el centerscreen, cuando inicia el programa inicia centrado pero a medida va cambiando su tamaño el formulario por el timer, no se queda centrado, sino que va hacia la derecha, como pudiera hacerle para que quede centrado?

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        circularProgressBar1.Value += 2;

        circularProgressBar1.Text = circularProgressBar1.Value.ToString();
        label3.Text = circularProgressBar1.Value.ToString();
        if (circularProgressBar1.Value == 20)
        {

            this.Size = new Size(500, 419);

        }
        if (circularProgressBar1.Value == 40)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(750, 419);

        }
        if (circularProgressBar1.Value == 60)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(1000, 419);
        }
        if (circularProgressBar1.Value == 80)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(1000, 550);
        }
        if (circularProgressBar1.Value == 100)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            timer2.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta centrar de nuevo el Form, después de cada Tick, una vez que cambies el tamaño. Porque en ningún momento estás cambiando la ubicación, sino solamente el tamaño. Creo que debería funcionar lo siguiente:

```
Form.CenterToScreen();
```

Que en tu caso, sería:

```
this.CenterToScreen();
```

Espero y eso sirva.